# What is the install routine for Common Lisp / SLIME/SBCL?

Tags: 15.04, lisp

Can someone give me a detailed install procedure for Common Lisp / SLIME / SBCL on Ubuntu?

Comment: What did you try? What were your problems?

Comment: I could install it with the help of the post below, I haven't found any procedure on the net for Ubuntu, so I had to ask here. Might be that LISP is not in general use anymore. Integrating it in Emacs might be harder. Can't I use Slime with Sublime Text?

Comment: I think I understand. You keep asking "How can I do X? How can I do Y?", but your decomposition of your problem into "X" and "Y" is probably not correct. Take a step back, and describe, in another question, what you are trying to accomplish (the thing that you think "do X" and "do Y" are part of).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for 14.04.03 LTS. In a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>), I would type:

```
# Note: the first part of the command line up to the "$ " is my prompt, 
# and not what I typed. I apologize for this if you know your a** from your
# elbow.

w3@aardvark:~(130)$ apt-cache search slime  

cl-swank - Superior LISP Interaction Mode for Emacs (Lisp-side server)
common-lisp-controller - Common Lisp source and compiler manager
sbcl-source - Source code files for SBCL
slime - Superior LISP Interaction Mode for Emacs
slimevolley - unrealistic 2D volleyball simulation
slimevolley-data - unrealistic 2D volleyball simulation - data files
stumpwm - tiling, keyboard driven Common Lisp window manager

# remove "--dry-run" to really install  

w3@aardvark:~(0)$ sudo apt-get --dry-run install slime 
[sudo] password for w3: 

# Your system's list of "additional" packages may vary. I have installed
# packages previously, and you may have, as well

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  cl-asdf cl-swank common-lisp-controller realpath
Suggested packages:
  sbcl darcs
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  cl-asdf cl-swank common-lisp-controller realpath slime
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
Inst cl-asdf (2:3.0.3-1 Ubuntu:14.04/trusty [all])
Inst cl-swank (1:20130626-1 Ubuntu:14.04/trusty [all])
Inst realpath (1.19 Ubuntu:14.04/trusty [amd64])
Inst common-lisp-controller (7.10 Ubuntu:14.04/trusty [all])
Inst slime (1:20130626-1 Ubuntu:14.04/trusty [all])
Conf cl-asdf (2:3.0.3-1 Ubuntu:14.04/trusty [all])
Conf cl-swank (1:20130626-1 Ubuntu:14.04/trusty [all])
Conf realpath (1.19 Ubuntu:14.04/trusty [amd64])
Conf common-lisp-controller (7.10 Ubuntu:14.04/trusty [all])
Conf slime (1:20130626-1 Ubuntu:14.04/trusty [all])

# Without "--dry-run" above, this would have installed slime
# and the following command would have listed the files in the slime package

w3@aardvark:~(0)$ dpkg -L slime
dpkg-query: package 'slime' is not installed
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
w3@aardvark:~(1)$
```

Comment: I still need to install Emacs I guess?

Comment: "Your system's list of "additional" packages may vary." It all depends on what you need. emacs may be included in your list of additional packages. emacs did not show up on my list of additional packages either because: a) slime doesn't need it; or b) I've had emacs installed on my systems since the beginning.

Comment: I've posted the output of your last command above. I want to use slime inside Emacs (as I don't think slime can be used with another editor). So how will I do use it with it? However Emacs is already installed on my system. So is sublime-text.

Comment: Since your `dpkg -L slime` showed you a list of files, you ALREADY have slime installed. Read the files `/usr/share/doc/slime/slime-refcard.pdf`, `/usr/share/doc/slime/slime.pdf`, `/usr/share/doc/slime/README.Debian`, `/usr/share/doc/slime/PROBLEMS`, and type `info slime`. Also look at `/etc/emacs/site-start.d/50slime.el`, which the `slime` package added to emacs startup. `man emacs`, `info emacs` as well.

Comment: Didn't say it isn't. The question is how I can integrate it in Emacs now easily. The slime.pdf uses a git clone. It's quite complicated compared with sublime text.

Comment: It's time to start another question - "What is the install routine for Common Lisp / SLIME/SBCL?" has morphed into "how I can integrate it in Emacs now easily. ". `/etc/emacs/site-start.d/50slime.el` (which is used when you START emacs) does the integration.

Comment: Okay, will start another thread then. I didn't spot any difference at startup so far.